# Tish'a Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred nineteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yehuda the son of Yaakov Avinu lived for 119 years

Parshas Shelach has 119 Pesukim

Psalm # 119 is the longest Psalm and the Perek with the most Pesukim in the entire Tanach!

Answer (score 2):

Nachor lived for 119 years after begetting Terach